# Why is my external function getting called on page load? JS

Tags: javascript, function, load

Why is my external function automatically getting called on page load even though I didnt call it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RuIV.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like line 14 of `fetchRandomUser.js` is calling the function that you want to export. I would omit line 14 and change line 3 to

```
export default async function fetchRandomUser() {
    // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I exported my function with "export default funcName;" instead of using "export async function funcName() {...}"